# Javascript Regex: How to remove JSON values matching any text after | including?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am saving a bunch of xpaths in a multiline string like this, using `anychar` to represent any characters:

```
anychar anychar 
anychar //chairs|//desks anychar //a
{"ignore|pipe": "//books|//*[@id=\"test\"]|//something"} anychar //b
```

and I expect :

```
anychar anychar 
anychar //chairs anychar //a
{"ignore|pipe": "//books"} anychar //b
```

basically I want to remove all extra `|//anyvalue` anywhere on the text

This is my attempt: `text.replace(/ *|//(*?)/g, "");`

I am not sure how to make it specifically look for `|//chars`

Comment: You need to escape `|` and `/` to match them literally.

Comment: `(*?)` makes no sense. You need a pattern before `*`. Did you mean `(.*?)`?

Comment: I need to only extract text like `|//(*?)` so escaping it would look like `\|\/\/(*?)` it seems.

Comment: You still need to make it `.*`. There's no need for the capture group. And there's no need to make it non-greedy if there's nothing after it.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to match `*` literally, too. You need to escape that as well.

Comment: no it is one of the examples, it could be * or any character really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this manually with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all the special characters in the regexp to treat them literally.

```
text.replace(/ *\|\/\/.*?"}/g, '"}');
```

We need to match the `"}` at the end and put it back into the replacement.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SBr0cG/1)

That could also be done using a lookahead.

Comment: this did not detect the `|//desks` in the previous line. I'm thinking maybe I should read each line and run this regex once.

Comment: So the `*` is not required in the match?

Comment: This may be hard to do with a regexp. The previous line doesn't have `"}` at the end. I'm not sure how to make it match that in one line, but not look for it in the other.

Comment: also this should not include the } in the end.

Comment: I see, I might have to just loop over each line and run regex replace